# Visual Studio Build Succeeded but dotnet build cli fails

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm attempting to run some tests on my project through a dotnet cli command. When I run the tests through visual studio, the projects build without any errors and the tests run fine. However, When I attempt to do a dotnet test command, I get many issues with "type or namespace xxx does not exist in namespace yyy" or "The type or namespace name xxx could not be found. I'm wondering what could cause the difference in the builds?

Comment: Having a similar issue right now